# Transforms applied by DataLoader in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I've noticed that PyTorch's DataLoader is applying scaling to the input data with the MNIST dataset. I'm guessing its some sort of normalisation or scaling, but how do I actually find what transform is being applied, and how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

It was the "ToTensor" transform used by the dataset, which scales the elements to the range [0,1].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).